# How to Query different rows from same table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
RowNum  ,Source_element,    source_value

1   ,    header1      ,      mail
1   ,    header2     ,       location
1   ,    header3     ,       address

2   ,    header1       ,     mail
2   ,    header2    ,        location
2   ,    header3    ,        US

3   ,    header1       ,     Email
3   ,    header2       ,     location
3   ,    header3      ,      Canada
```

Above is the table that i am having. 
Currently as example i am using 3 records for each Rownum but it can be any based on source file that we are getting

I need to write a query where

> if header1=mail and header3=US for any given same rownum then extract that rownum 2

or

> if header1=Email and header2=location and header3=Canada then extract rownum 3

Any leads would really help me..i am totally clue less on how to proceed.

Comment: Can you give examples of the results you want?  I'm not sure what you meant by `then extract that rownum 2` and `then extract that rownum 3`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on what you actually want, but the starting point is to use conditional aggregation.  That is `CASE` expressions and `MIN()`,`MAX()`,`SUM()` aggregate functions.

For example...

```
WITH
  pivoted AS
(
  SELECT
    rownum,
    MAX(CASE WHEN source_element = 'header1' THEN source_value END) AS header1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN source_element = 'header2' THEN source_value END) AS header2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN source_element = 'header2' THEN source_value END) AS header3
  FROM
    yourTable
  GROUP BY
    rownum
)
SELECT
  <something>
FROM
  pivoted
WHERE
  (header1='mail' AND header3='US')
  OR
  (header1='Email' AND header2='location' AND header3='Canada')
```

Hopefully that will get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Not elegant, but:

```
    CREATE TABLE Demo
    (
     Row_Num        VARCHAR2(0016)
    ,Source_Element VARCHAR2(0016)
    ,Source_Value   VARCHAR2(0016)
    );

INSERT INTO Demo (Row_Num,Source_Element,Source_Value)
SELECT * FROM
(
      SELECT '1' AS Row_Num, 'header1' AS Source_Element, 'mail' AS Source_Value FROM dual
UNION SELECT '1' AS Row_Num, 'header2' AS Source_Element, 'location' AS Source_Value FROM dual
UNION SELECT '1' AS Row_Num, 'header3' AS Source_Element, 'address' AS Source_Value FROM dual
--
UNION SELECT '2' AS Row_Num, 'header1' AS Source_Element, 'mail' AS Source_Value FROM dual
UNION SELECT '2' AS Row_Num, 'header2' AS Source_Element, 'location' AS Source_Value FROM dual
UNION SELECT '2' AS Row_Num, 'header3' AS Source_Element, 'US' AS Source_Value FROM dual
--
UNION SELECT '3' AS Row_Num, 'header1' AS Source_Element, 'Email' AS Source_Value FROM dual
UNION SELECT '3' AS Row_Num, 'header2' AS Source_Element, 'location' AS Source_Value FROM dual
UNION SELECT '3' AS Row_Num, 'header3' AS Source_Element, 'Canada' AS Source_Value FROM dual
);

SELECT row_num
FROM
(
SELECT
     h1.row_num
    ,h1.source_value        AS Header_1
    ,h2.source_value        AS Header_2
    ,h3.source_value        AS Header_3
FROM demo h1
    --
    JOIN demo h2
        ON h2.row_num = h1.row_num
    --
    JOIN demo h3
        ON h3.row_num = h2.row_num
WHERE (1 = 1)
  AND h1.source_element = 'header1'
  AND h2.source_element = 'header2'
  AND h3.source_element = 'header3'
)
WHERE (1 = 1)
  AND header_1 = 'mail'
  AND header_3 = 'US'
;
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a case where you would want to use `PIVOT`. Something like the following:

```
SELECT "RowNum" FROM
(
  SELECT "RowNum", source_element, source_value
  FROM testtable
)
PIVOT
(
  max(source_value)
  FOR source_element IN ('header1','header2','header3')
)
WHERE
 ("'header1'"='mail' and "'header3'"='US')
 OR
 ("'header1'"='Email' and "'header2'"='location' and "'header3'"='Canada')
;
```

Here is an example of [it working with your sample data.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c20af/11/0)

The basic idea is that the `PIVOT` turns your header1/header2/header3 rows into columns and you can then apply a condition to a single row.